# Is this a bug with new version of watchOS or iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to setup a button to play audio through the `AVPlayer` in a watch `application`.

I've already tried some of the previous `players`, like `WKInterfaceInlineMovie` and I tried to be precise in terms of what `AVPlayer` expects, with no success.

```swift
class Clicker {

    private let soundFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "click_sound_1", withExtension: "wav")

    private func setupAVPlayer() -> AVPlayer {
        let soundURL = self.soundFile!
        let soundAsset = AVAsset(url: soundURL)
        let soundItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: soundAsset)
        let avplayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: soundItem)
        avplayer.rate = 1.0
        return avplayer
    }

    func playClicker() {
        self.setupAVPlayer().play()
    }

}


struct ClickerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            Clicker().playClicker()

            }, label: {
                Text("Play")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Instead of playing any audio, all I get is output in the console.
I get no crashing. At the very least I thought I would get a crash for missing file, or wrong URL.

> 2019-09-12 12:48:02.593282+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.593] <<<< FigPlayerSurrogate >>>> FigPlayerSurrogateCreateWithOptions: new player 0x7a192270 P/FR
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.594368+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189282] [] [12:48:02.594] <<<< FigPlayerSurrogate >>>> surrogatePlayer_CreatePlaybackItemFromAsset: [0x7a192270] P/FR Created new item 0x7a0be4a0 I/GKA.01
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.602349+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.602] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> FigPlayerPlaybackStateGetNextState: [0x7a0beda0] P/FR called. reason ClientPolicyChanged, options: - -
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.602490+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.602] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> FigPlayerPlaybackStateGetNextState: [0x7a0beda0] P/FR player rate is 0. new playback state Paused
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.602574+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.603] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> FigPlayerPlaybackStateGetNextState: P/FR new playback state: Paused (playerRate: 0.000), DON'T need to update item rate (nan). Previous state: Paused, change reason: ClientPolicyChanged
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.602796+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.603] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> fp_CreatePlaybackItem: [0x7a0beda0] P/FR  asset 0x7a194060 -> new item 0x7a912e00 I/GKA.01
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.604419+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.604] <<<< FigPlayerSurrogate >>>> surrogatePlaybackItem_createRealItemInternal: created real item 0x7a912e00 for surrogate item 0x7a0be4a0 I/GKA.01
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.604643+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.605] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> itemfig_SetCurrentTimeWithRangeAndID: [0x7a912e00] I/GKA.01 called, time = 0.000, flags = 0x3, range = [-inf, inf], seekID = 0
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.604783+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189260] [] [12:48:02.605] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> itemfig_SetCurrentTimeWithRangeAndID: [0x7a912e00] I/GKA.01 to 0.000 - setting remembered time
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.605292+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189282] [] [12:48:02.605] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> itemfig_Invalidate: [0x7a912e00] I/GKA.01 called
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.605721+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189282] [] [12:48:02.606] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> playerfig_Invalidate: [0x7a0beda0] P/FR
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.605886+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189282] [] [12:48:02.606] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> playerfig_RemoveFromPlayQueue: [0x7a0beda0] P/FR item 0x0 
>   2019-09-12 12:48:02.606583+0300 Clicker WatchKit Extension[4439:189220] [] [12:48:02.607] <<<< FigFilePlayer >>>> playerfig_Invalidate: [0x7a0beda0] P/FR

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure the asset is loaded before you play it.
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading/1387321-loadvaluesasynchronously

   ```
   func playClicker() {
       // Load the asset's "playable" key
       asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["playable"]) {
       var error: NSError? = nil
       let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
       switch status {
           case .loaded:
           // Sucessfully loaded, continue processing
               self.setupAVPlayer().play()
           case .failed:
           // Examine NSError pointer to determine failure
           case .cancelled:
           // Loading cancelled
           default:
               // Handle all other cases
           }
       }
   }
   ```